# I have a DataFrame, I need a required format from it. I am putting more details below

Tags: julia, dataframes.jl

I have a DataFrame in the following format:

```
julia> using DataFrames, CSV

julia> str = """Roll,id,name,tag,date1,date2,date3,date4,date5
       0001443646-19-000093,1443646,Rohit,Student,20170331,20180331,20190331
       0001443646-20-000086,1443646,Rohit,Student,20190331,20200331,20180331
       0001443646-21-000079,1443646,Rohit,Student,20190331,20210331,20200331
       0001683168-20-001021,1622879,Mohit,Teacher,20191231
       0001683168-21-001161,1622879,Mohit,Teacher,20201231,20191231
       """
"Roll,id,name,tag,date1,date2,date3,date4,date5\n0001443646-19-000093,1443646,Rohit,Student,20170331,20180331,20190331\n0001443646-20-000086,1443646,Rohit,Student,20190331,20200331,20180331\n0001443646-21-000079,1443646,Rohit,Student,20190331,20210331,20200331\n0001683168-20-001021,1622879,Mohit,Teacher,20191231\n0001683168-21-001161,1622879,Mohit,Teacher,20201231,20191231\n"

julia> df = CSV.read(IOBuffer(str), DataFrame)
5×9 DataFrame
 Row │ Roll                  id       name    tag      date1     date2     date3     date4    date5
     │ String                Int64    String  String   Int64     Int64?    Int64?    Missing  Missing
─────┼────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
   1 │ 0001443646-19-000093  1443646  Rohit   Student  20170331  20180331  20190331  missing  missing
   2 │ 0001443646-20-000086  1443646  Rohit   Student  20190331  20200331  20180331  missing  missing
   3 │ 0001443646-21-000079  1443646  Rohit   Student  20190331  20210331  20200331  missing  missing
   4 │ 0001683168-20-001021  1622879  Mohit   Teacher  20191231   missing   missing  missing  missing
   5 │ 0001683168-21-001161  1622879  Mohit   Teacher  20201231  20191231   missing  missing  missing
```

Now, first, let's talk about `df` and let's talk about 1st name in `:name` column which is `Rohit`.  So, the `id` and `tags` are the same for `name` `Rohit` but the string in Roll is different and there is some duplicates date for that particular name. So, now let's have a look at simplified DataFrame `df1` and I will talk about how I manipulated it manually:

Now, the target DataFrame I want to achieve is:

```
julia> df1 = CSV.read(IOBuffer(str), DataFrame)
2×9 DataFrame
 Row │ Roll                  id       name    tag      date1     date2     date3     date4     date5
     │ String                Int64    String  String   Int64     Int64     Int64?    Int64?    Int64?
─────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
   1 │ 0001443646-21-000079  1443646  Rohit   Student  20210331  20210331  20190331  20180331  20170331
   2 │ 0001683168-21-001161  1622879  Mohit   Teacher  20201231  20191231   missing   missing   missing
```

Lets focus on some points:

1. First lets focus on `:Roll` column. In this column you will see there are three different roll strings, for example, `0001443646-21-000079` now here in the between `21` is our higher precedence to consider in comparison to the other two strings  `0001443646-20-000086`, and `0001443646-19-000093` where we will get `20`, and `19` respectively. So according to `0001443646-21-000079` the extracted dates will be:

```
20190331,20210331,20200331,missing,missing
```

But now I will make a decreasing order again (means we will put recent years first followed by past years), for examples,

```
20210331,20200331,20190331,missing,missing
```

same for the other two strings:

```
0001443646-19-000093,1443646,Rohit,Student,20190331,20180331,20170331,missing,missing
0001443646-20-000086,1443646,Rohit,Student,20200331,20190331,20180331,missing,missing
```

Now, as we will consider higher precedence Roll first so if we will encounter duplicates from other two roll string we will not consider it. The final format for name `Rohit` will look like this:

```
0001443646-21-000079,1443646,Rohit,Student,20210331,20210331,20190331,20180331,20170331
```

If you will see in other two Roll strings we are having duplicates. Now, I want to convert the whole idea into the script format. I am having some difficulties with it. Can someone will help me?

Comment: please try to simplify your problem and ask a clear question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hey @MarcMush I have added the targetted dataframe which I want to achieve and I have explained clearly that how I achieved it manually and now I want to write a script for that targetted dataframe. Please can you tell me which point is unclear to you? Thank you!

Comment: also double check in your data that indeed you have `"missing"` string there (as in your question), and not `missing` value instead.

Comment: It was `missing` value not `"missing"` string. I have corrected it. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using DataFrames.jl 1.2.2 and CSV.jl 0.9.2 (current versions).

Then do:

```
julia> df = CSV.read(IOBuffer(str), DataFrame, stringtype=String)
5×9 DataFrame
 Row │ Roll                  id       name    tag      date1     date2     date3     date4    date5
     │ String                Int64    String  String   Int64     String    String    String   String
─────┼────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
   1 │ 0001443646-19-000093  1443646  Rohit   Student  20170331  20180331  20190331  missing  missing
   2 │ 0001443646-20-000086  1443646  Rohit   Student  20190331  20200331  20180331  missing  missing
   3 │ 0001443646-21-000079  1443646  Rohit   Student  20190331  20210331  20200331  missing  missing
   4 │ 0001683168-20-001021  1622879  Mohit   Teacher  20191231  missing   missing   missing  missing
   5 │ 0001683168-21-001161  1622879  Mohit   Teacher  20201231  20191231  missing   missing  missing

julia> df.date1 = string.(df.date1) # need to do it as in your example you are mixing string and integer columns later
5-element Vector{String}:
 "20170331"
 "20190331"
 "20190331"
 "20191231"
 "20201231"

julia> combine(groupby(df, :name)) do sdf
       df2 = sort(sdf, by=x->parse(Int, split(x,"-")[2]), rev=true)
       dfr = first(df2)
       pos=findfirst(==("missing"), Vector(dfr[r"date"]))
       for i in 2:nrow(df2), n in names(df2, r"date")
           if !(df2[i, n] in Vector(dfr[r"date"])) && df2[i, n] != "missing"
               pos > 5 && error("unsupported data")
               dfr[r"date"][pos] = df2[i, n]
               pos += 1
           end
       end
       dfr[r"date"][1:pos-1] = sort(Vector(dfr[r"date"][1:pos-1]), rev=true)
       return dfr
       end
2×9 DataFrame
 Row │ name    Roll                  id       tag      date1     date2     date3     date4     date5
     │ String  String                Int64    String   String    String    String    String    String
─────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
   1 │ Rohit   0001443646-21-000079  1443646  Student  20210331  20200331  20190331  20180331  20170331
   2 │ Mohit   0001683168-21-001161  1622879  Teacher  20201231  20191231  missing   missing   missing
```

This is not an optimized code - I was just writing along reading your description. I hope it shows you how you can approach the task.

---

If you have `missing` not `"missing"` do e.g.:

```
julia> df.date4 = missings(Int, 5)
5-element Vector{Union{Missing, Int64}}:
 missing
 missing
 missing
 missing
 missing

julia> df.date5 = missings(Int, 5)
5-element Vector{Union{Missing, Int64}}:
 missing
 missing
 missing
 missing
 missing

julia> combine(groupby(df, :name)) do sdf
           df2 = sort(sdf, by=x->parse(Int, split(x,"-")[2]), rev=true)
           dfr = first(df2)
           pos=findfirst(ismissing, Vector(dfr[r"date"]))
           for i in 2:nrow(df2), n in names(df2, r"date")
               if !ismissing(df2[i, n]) && !(any(x -> isequal(df2[i, n], x), dfr[r"date"]))
                   pos > 5 && error("unsupported data")
                   dfr[r"date"][pos] = df2[i, n]
                   pos += 1
               end
           end
           dfr[r"date"][1:pos-1] = sort(Vector(dfr[r"date"][1:pos-1]), rev=true)
           return dfr
       end
2×9 DataFrame
 Row │ name     Roll                  id       tag      date1     date2     date3     date4     date5
     │ String7  String31              Int64    String7  Int64     Int64?    Int64?    Int64?    Int64?
─────┼───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
   1 │ Rohit    0001443646-21-000079  1443646  Student  20210331  20200331  20190331  20180331  20170331
   2 │ Mohit    0001683168-21-001161  1622879  Teacher  20201231  20191231   missing   missing   missing
```